# Apply synonyms while typing tags

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-synonyms, tag-autocomplete

When I type in a tag that is a synonym source, a box with the synonym target pops up. This is good because when I am somewhat paying attention and know about synonyms, I see what kind of change will be applied once I submit my question and can change my mind if needed, e.g., when I notice that the tag is not about what I thought it was.

However, when I just continue typing, no synonymisation happens. For example, here on Meta SE, [html](/questions/tagged/html) points to [design](/questions/tagged/design) and I get this:

[image: GIF showing the UI behaviour]

If I type with ignoring the boxes that pop up or have no idea how synonymisation works, this can lead to confusion. In the above example, I might get the impression that HTML (in general) is a fine topic to ask here. Or I might end up with a mistagged question because [html](/questions/tagged/html) makes sense for my question, but [design](/questions/tagged/design) doesn’t.

Therefore I request that once I finished typing a synonym source into the tag field (e.g., when hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> after typing it), it gets automatically replaced with the synonym target.

*This feature request arose from [this comment](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/rename-errors-erratum-to-errata-with-respective-synonyms#comment16247_5147) on Meta Academia.*

Comment: I suspect this could be just as confusing for unfamiliar users; I imagine having your tag in the input get silently swapped without warning could frustrate someone in much the same way as the current functionality does. There should really be some sort of banner or something indicating that the swap occurred.

Comment: @zcoop98: I would say that the proposed way is at least a bit less silent than the old one, since at least the asker has a chance to see it. But I fully concur that some explicit indication would be even better.